# Find only files with certain extension. for /R "c:\" %A in (*.tmp) not working as expected

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I've found other answers related to 8.3 filenames and such, but that's not the problem here.

I'm using Windows 7 at the command prompt.

I run this: `for /R "c:\" %A in (*.tmp) do echo "%A"`, and it finds all files with .TMP as an extension, but also finds my test file with .TMP123 as its extension:

Examples:

```
"c:\Users\random\AppData\Local\Temp\~DFDCC0F94DFE245596.TMP"
"c:\Windows\Temp\Testfile.tmp123"
```

I've also tried this: `for /R "c:\" %A in ("*.tmp") do echo "%A"`,
and this: `for /R "c:\" %A in (*."tmp") do echo "%A"`, and the results are the same.

Edit: It doesn't show, but that's a *.tmp in the parentheses above.

This also happens when searching for other extensions so it's not just .tmp files that are doing this.

Is there a way to limit this so that it only finds files with just .TMP as the extension?

Comment: Why not just do c:\> dir /s *.tmp ?

Comment: I'm wanting the full path and file name on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either filter the extension:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S C:\*.tmp ^|findstr /ec:".tmp"') do @echo %A
```

Or check the extension with `~`-modifiers

```
for /R "c:\" %A in ("*.tmp") do @if /i "%~xA"==".tmp" @echo %A
```

Comment: Both of those worked, mostly. They both excluded the .TMP123 file, but the results were not identical.

Comment: Just tested but had only one file and the same output. Starting from root will probaply cause rights issues but that should be same for both variants.

Comment: The first command found .tmp file(s) in c:\Users\random\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data as well as some here c:\Users\random\AppData\Local\Temp that the second command didn't.

The second command found .tmp file(s) in C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Temp that the first one didn't. These were also not found by my original command line.

I should also point out that dir *.tmp /s /b (from C:\) includes all the files that each command finds, including some in C:\Windows\Installer named MSI3129.tmp- (with a dash at the end), but none of the other commands show these.